# Mongo multiple $lookup in any collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

### I'm trying to set up a query on the mongo that searches in 3 different collections.

Document of client:

```
{  
   "_id": ObjectId("1a")
   "razaosocial:"32423424",
   "prepository": [
     {
       "$ref": "prepository",
       "$id": ObjectId("2a")
     }
   ]
}
```

Document of prepository:

```
{  
   "_id": ObjectId("2a")
   "name:"Jonh",
   "prepository": {
       "$ref": "representative",
       "$id": ObjectId("3a")
     }
}
```

Document of representative:

```
{  
   "_id": ObjectId("3a")
   "name:"Josh"
}
```

I'm doing it this way, but it doesn't return anything:

```
db.clients.aggregate(
[
  {
     $lookup: {
            from: 'prepository',
            localField: 'prepository',
            foreignField: 'id',
            as: 'prepository'
     }
  },  
  { $unwind: "$prepository" },
  { $lookup: {
    from: 'representative',
    localField: 'id',
    foreignField: 'prepository._id',
    as: 'prepository.repre'
   }
  },
  { $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    client: { $first: "$razaosocial" },
    users: {
      $push: "$prepository"
   }
  } }
])
```

I'm trying to return

```
{  
   "_id": "1a"
   "razaosocial:"32423424",
   "prepository": [
      {
         "_id": "2a"
         "name:"Jonh",
         "representative": {
            "_id": "3a"
            "name:"Josh"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I am grateful for any help

Comment: Yes, I'll correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested lookup,

- `$lookup` with `prepository` collection
- `$match` with `prepository`'s id
- `$lookup` with `representative` collection
- `$unwind` deconstruct `representative` array

```
db.client.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "prepository",
      as: "prepository",
      let: { prepository: "$prepository" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$prepository"] } } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "representative",
            localField: "representative",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "representative"
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$representative" }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R_lvG1qQk5E)